# A turning gear appears when I run Automator app. Can i replace it?

Tags: automator, notifications, customization

I am running the shell script using automator.

However, I get the following in the statusbar:

[image: Screenshot with turning gear in notification area]

The question is... Can i customize this icon? Replace with my own?

Comment: That status item is in the system frameworks, and used for Automator and AppleScript progress. What _exactly_ are you wanting to do?

Comment: I want to replace this turning gear for a cup of coffee for my Automator app. And i'm not a programmer. Is there an easy way?

Comment: There isn't an easy way to change that icon or menu. Note that the "progress" just indicates the individual workflow actions that have completed, not whatever the shell script is doing, so an app or script would be needed to provide specific progress.